# Mocha not running unit tests through webpack 2

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, expect, babeljs, enzyme

I'm having a issue running Mocha, Expect and Enzyme. First, I transpile my webpack config file through babel. Below is an attached screenshot of the error I get and the test files are valid. Anyone had the similar issue?

[image: Badbadbad]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your babel configuration look like? Make sure that you're including the transform to handle import statements. Normally you'd do this with the `babel-preset-es2015` plugin

Comment: have you transpiled your .test files as well. The error clearly says o Mocha is unable to resolve `import` keyword i.e `ES 2015` syntax. I think you need to transpile your .test files to `ES5` and then run mocha against to ES5 files.

Comment: try `var expect = require('expect');`

Comment: @Venky, if I understand him correctly, his question is "how do I use ES6 modules in my mocha tests?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're showing me your webpack config, not your babel config. But, based on what I'm seeing though I'm guessing that you're using [`babel-preset-es2015-webpack`](http://npm.im/babel-preset-es2015-webpack) which excludes the transform to transpile es6 modules ([`babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs)). You'll want to include that for your tests. You can do this in the same way I show you how to include the `babel-plugin-__coverage__` plugin in [this lesson](https://egghead.io/lessons/tools-add-code-coverage-to-tests-in-a-webpack-project?course=using-webpack-for-production-javascript-applications). Also check out [cross-env](http://npm.im/cross-env) to set `BABEL_ENV` to test.

Also, you're using `babel-core/register` which will be deprecated. You'll want to use the [`babel-register`](http://npm.im/babel-register) package instead.

So your script will probably look like:

```
"test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test mocha --harmony --compilers js:babel-register --recursive src/__tests__"
```

Comment: I've used babel-register too check as well, no luck. Also, the command you gave gave the same error :(

Comment: yep <3 Thanks for the fix Kent <3 <3 Getting useful errors now!